# Pipeline tab is missing in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDqp9.png)

Please, i am unable to see the pipeline tab on Jenkins page as shown in pic. Can someone comment on this?

Answer (score 0):

if you mean you can't see an option to create a pipeline job; then for that, you need to click on "New item" on the top in the left-hand menu. Second - you need the pipeline plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-aggregator